# Erasing in HTML5 canvas (even in IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, html, canvas

I'm woking on the tool that allows user to erase areas on canvas element. I used globalCompositeOperation="copy" and rgba(0,0,0,0).

It works well in modern browsers but not in IE. I also use excanvas.js but erasing doesn't work at all.

Are there any way to implement erasing in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that canvas is not supported in IE, and excanvas.js does not implement all functions of canvas, including globalCompositeOperation--

see http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/issues/detail?id=10

As for an alternative, could you link to the code so that we have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish?